# Postgresql order by out of order

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, psql

I have a database where I need to retrieve the data as same order as it was populated in the table. The table name is bible When I type in `table bible;` in psql, it prints the data in the order it was populated with, but when I try to retrieve it, some rows are always out of order as in the below example:

`table bible`

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      | 1
day     | 1
book    | Genesis
chapter | 1
verse   | 1
text    | In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
link    | https://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/asv.txt.txt?passage=Genesis1.1&amp;key=dc5e2d416f46150bf6ceb21d884b644f
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      | 2
day     | 1
book    | John
chapter | 1
verse   | 1
text    | In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
link    | https://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/asv.txt.txt?passage=John1.1&amp;key=dc5e2d416f46150bf6ceb21d884b644f
-[ RECORD 3 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      | 3
day     | 1
book    | John
chapter | 1
verse   | 2
text    | The same was in the beginning with God.
link    | https://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/asv.txt.txt?passage=John1.2&amp;key=dc5e2d416f46150bf6ceb21d884b644f
```

Everything is in order, but when I try to query the same thing using for example: `select * from bible where day='1'` or `select * from bible where day='1' order by day` or `select * from bible where day='1' order by day, id;`, I always get some rows out of order either in the day selected (here 1) or any other day.
I have been using Django to interfere with Postgres database, but since I found this problem, I tried to query using SQL, but nothing, I still get rows out of order, although they all have unique ids which I verified with `select count(distinct id), count(id) from bible;`

```
- [ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      | 1
day     | 1
book    | Genesis
chapter | 1
verse   | 1
text    | In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
link    | https://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/asv.txt.txt?passage=Genesis1.1&amp;key=dc5e2d416f46150bf6ceb21d884b644f
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      | 10
day     | 1
book    | Colossians
chapter | 1
verse   | 18
text    | And he is the head of the body, the church: who is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead; that in all things he might have the preemine
nce.
link    | https://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/asv.txt.txt?passage=Colossians1.18&amp;key=dc5e2d416f46150bf6ceb21d884b644f
-[ RECORD 3 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      | 11
day     | 1
book    | Genesis
chapter | 1
verse   | 2
text    | And the earth was waste and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep: and the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
link    | https://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/asv.txt.txt?passage=Genesis1.2&amp;key=dc5e2d416f46150bf6ceb21d884b644f
```

As you could see above if you notice, the ids are out of order 1, 10, 11.

my table

```
                              Table "public.bible";
Column  | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------+------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
id      | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
day     | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
book    | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
chapter | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
verse   | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
text    | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
link    | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
Access method: heap
```

The id field is of type text because I used pandas's `to_sql()` method to populate the bible table. I tried to drop the id column and then I added it again as a PK with `ALTER TABLE bible ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;` but I still get data return out of order.

Is there anyway I can retrieve the data with ordering with id, without having some of the rows totally out of order? Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have any index?

Comment: @sddk  Ah, no indexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thou shalt `cast` thy `id` to integer to order it as number.

```
SELECT * FROM bible ORDER BY cast(id AS integer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on both answers of @jordanvrtanoski and @Javier Buzzi, and some search online, the issue is because the ids are of type TEXT (or VARCHAR too), so, you would need to cast the id to type INTEGER as in the following:

`ALTER TABLE bible ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer USING (id::integer);`

Now here is my table

```
                                                Table "public.bible"
Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
id      | integer |           |          | nextval('bible_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
day     | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
book    | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
chapter | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
verse   | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
text    | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
link    | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "lesson_unique_id" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "notes_note" CONSTRAINT "notes_note_verse_id_5586a4bf_fk" FOREIGN KEY (verse_id) REFERENCES days_lesson(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Access method: heap
```

Hope this helps other people, and thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

While @jordanvrtanoski is correct, the way to do this is django is:

```
>>> Bible.objects.extra(select={'id': 'CAST(id AS INTEGER)'}).order_by('id').values('id')
<QuerySet [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 10}, {'id': 20}]>
```

Side note: If you want to filter on `day` as an example, you can do this:

```
>>> Bible.objects.extra(select={
    'id': 'CAST(id AS INTEGER)', 
    'day': 'CAST(day AS INTEGER)'}
).order_by('id').values('id', 'day').filter(day=2)
<QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'day': 2}, {'id': 10, 'day': 2}, {'id': 11, 'day': 2}, {'id': 20, 'day': 2}]>
```

Otherwise you get this issue: (notice `1` is followed by `10` and not `2`)

```
>>> Bible.objects.order_by('id').values('id')
<QuerySet [{'id': '1'}, {'id': '10'}, {'id': '2'}, {'id': '20'}, {'id': '3'}]>
```

*I HIGHLY suggest you* **DO NOT** *do any of this, and set your tables correctly (have the correct column types and not have everything as `text`), or your query performance is going to suck.. BIG TIME*

Comment: thank you for your response! I am however using filter on objects just as in the row SQL ( `...WHERE day='1'`), so when I tried appending the extra method to the filter result, I am getting a queryset of objects of ids as in your second code snippet, do you know please of a way to apply your select method on Bible.objects.filter(day=1).extra...? Thanks a lot

Comment: I have edited your answer so the queryset returns the ordered objects just like the SQL equivalence. Thank your @Javier Buzzi

Comment: I have managed to make it work following your example; ended up with `Bible.objects.filter(day=day).extra({ 'id':"CAST(id as INTEGER)"}).order_by('id')`

Comment: I have dropped the text ids first as I have mentioned in the post, and replaced them with integer PK, but for some reason, they still get returned out of order, any thoughts, sir?

Comment: Something else is interfering, i would suggest you debug it, look at `Bible.objects.extra(..).filter(..).order_by(..).query.__str__()` and debug the sql. Something tells me is your configuration/code and not django/postgres.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, I have posted an answer, and you are right, what was interfering was an id field I set on the model with a primary_key=True, and it throws an error such as "id is ambiguous", so I just dropped the id (I forgot it through trying to fix the error), made migrations, and all is good, I also now don't rely on Django's extra method, because as you have mentioned, it's not the best thing, so I CAST the id field on the table to INTEGER. Thank you for your help!!